# Flagged Posts font size and layout

Tags: discussion, design, flag-history

What is going on with the font size and line spacing on the Flagged Posts page in the new design for SO.

The font size for the links is 18px and to me looks much nicer at a 16px or 14px.

Then as the lovely hand drawn lines illustrate there is some kind of alignment issue.

Maybe this is just a "Argh it's changed!" issue but it doesn't look quite right to me.

> [image: Showing space & hand draw lines FTW]

Comment: I've been trying to say to myself the same but no, this is not *argh it's changed!* effect anymore. I'm finding those titles really big too (*hiding* the other information on that page).

Comment: @TLama yeah agreed every time I look at it I think my browser must be zoomed in or something